# Code works in Watch Window, but unable to cast object during code execution

Tags: c#, .net, inheritance

I have these lines of code in my `.NET 4.7.2` server application:

```
object saveObject = proxyDef.GetEntityAsNativeObject(entity, DynamicProxyAssembly); // this works
((AxdSalesOrder)saveObject).SalesTable[0].TableDlvAddr = null; // this throws error
```

I can execute the null-set (2nd line above) in the `VS2019 Watch Window` and it works perfectly and achieves the desired effect. But when I allow it to run in normal execution (whether in debug mode or not), I get an unhandled exception on that 2nd line:

> Unable to cast object of type 'AxdSalesOrder' to type
> 'Elogix.MSAx.Core.Ax2012ElogixServices.AxdSalesOrder'

There is dynamic stuff going in in relation to that type:

```
public override object GetEntityAsNativeObject(MSAxEntity entity, Assembly dynamicProxyAssembly) {
  var salesOrderObject = Activator.CreateInstance(dynamicProxyAssembly.GetType("AxdSalesOrder"));

  var salesOrderTable = DynamicEntityUtil.CreateObjectFromDynamicEntity(entity, dynamicProxyAssembly, "AxdEntity_SalesTable");

  Array tableLines =
    Array.CreateInstance(
      salesOrderObject.GetType().GetProperty("SalesTable").PropertyType.GetElementType(), 1);

  tableLines.SetValue(salesOrderTable, 0);
  salesOrderObject.SetPropertyValue("SalesTable", tableLines);
  return salesOrderObject;
}

public static object CreateObjectFromDynamicEntity(DynamicEntity entity, Assembly dynamicProxyAssembly, string objectTypeName) {
  return CreateObjectFromDynamicEntity(entity, dynamicProxyAssembly.GetType(objectTypeName));
}

public static object CreateObjectFromDynamicEntity(DynamicEntity entity, Type type) {
  if (type == null) {
    throw new ArgumentException("Cannot create object from dynamic entity because \"Type\" is null.");
  }

  if (type.IsArray) {
    return CreateArrayFromDynamicEntity(entity, type);
  }

  return CreateClassFromDynamicEntity(entity, type);
}

private static object CreateClassFromDynamicEntity(DynamicEntity entity, Type type) {
  var nativeObject = Activator.CreateInstance(type);

  // this will recursively convert the dynamic values to the native type values on the object.
  updateValuesFromDynamicValues(entity);

  var modifiedProperties = from property in entity.Properties
  //where property.State != DynamicPropertyState.Unchanged
  select property;

  foreach(var property in modifiedProperties) {
    Type valueUnderlyingType = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(property.Type);
    if (valueUnderlyingType != null && valueUnderlyingType.IsEnum) {
      PropertyInfo info = nativeObject.GetType().GetProperty(property.Name);
      Type targetUnderlyingType = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(info.PropertyType);

      if (property.Value == null) {
        info.SetValue(nativeObject, null, null);
      } else {
        object correctedValue = property.Value.CorrectedEnumValue(targetUnderlyingType);
        info.SetValue(nativeObject, correctedValue, null);
      }
    } else if (property.Type.IsEnum) {
      if (property.Value == null) {
        continue;
      }
      object correctedValue = property.Value.CorrectedEnumValue(property.Type);
      nativeObject.SetPropertyValue(property.Name, correctedValue);
    } else {
      try {
        nativeObject.SetPropertyValue(property.Name, property.Value);
      } catch (Exception ex) {
        Log.Write(ex.Message);
      }
    }
  }

  return nativeObject;
}
```

Here is how it looks in the VS2019 `Watch Window`:

[image]

Did this in `Immediate Window`:

```
var t = saveObject.GetType();
t.FullName
"AxdSalesOrder"
```

As you can see, the type's `FullName` is not very full, not qualified by anything, due to the dynamic nature of the type.

I can try it this way:

```
(saveObject as AxdSalesOrder).SalesTable[0].TableDlvAddr = null;
```

Again, that works in Watch, but throws this exception when run in normal execution:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Clearly, VS/Watch *knows the type*, which is why it can execute without errors inside Watch. But the .net runtime apparently *doesn't know the type* at run time. How can I get this object cast to work in normal code execution like it does when run in Watch?

Comment: You possibly have two or more types of the same name. The one bound with using (so that you don't have the full type name but just the class name) is the other one. Just put a full type name there (include the namespace).

Comment: Wiktor : I don't know the full type name, that's the problem. And the type has dynamic stuff going on that I don't really understand.

Comment: Forget the type, declare as dynamic then.

Comment: Could you provide an SCCE? It looks like you're using Entity Framework, and that will change things.

Comment: Ian: Not using EF. Wiktor: I tried this: `dynamic saveObject = proxyDef.GetEntityAsNativeObject(entity, DynamicProxyAssembly);` - didn't help, same error on next line.

Comment: Drop casting from the next line if you declare as `dynamic`. Just `saveObject.SalesTable[0].TableDlvAddr = null;` should do.

Comment: @HerrimanCoder: drop a note if this helps

Comment: Wiktor: Success! Thank you very much! Can you post your answer formally so I can accept it, and hopefully help others?

Comment: @HerrimanCoder: Great, posted the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer here is to take advantage of dynamic typing since the static type is not available here:

```
dynamic saveObject = proxyDef.GetEntityAsNativeObject(entity, DynamicProxyAssembly); 
saveObject.SalesTable[0].TableDlvAddr = null;
```

Another possible approach would be to use reflection, however since the expression applied to the object involves two properties and an index lookup (`.SalesTable[0].TableDlvAddr`) this would look much less readable.

The `GetEntityAsNativeObject` could also benefit from this style, you could consider rewriting it to using dynamic binding rather than reflection.